# Excel: How to extract numbers from a string

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

Can anyone help me extract the numbers before `E` and the numbers between `E` and `B` into two separate cells? The number length can vary for both positions.

`8E20B1PSP13`

Comment: Can you post some more examples? What if there are also letters before E? What if there is no B in the string? ...

Comment: 25E158B1PL1   Some times there will be 1-100 in the first position and 1-15000 between "E" and "B" need to separate like the below Key into 6 different cells if you can help. Key coming Next

Comment: (10)(E)(100)(B)(1)(PL1)

Comment: for example that PL1 could be PL4 or PSP13 etc.

Comment: there will always be no letters before E just numeric values

Comment: please don't provide additional information in comments, but edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use text functions along with the `FIND` function.

Assuming your code is in cell A1:

`LEFT(A1,FIND("E",A1)-1)` will extract the first number.

`MID(A1,FIND("E",A1)+1,FIND("B",A1)-FIND("E",A1)-1)` will extract the second number

**Test cases:**

[image: Example values test]

Answer (score 0):

You really should lookup how to use Excel's text functions at these links: [LEN()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-len-function), [LEFT()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-left-function), [MID()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-mid-function), [RIGHT()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-right-function), and [FIND()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-find-function).

Your revised request is this:

> Sometimes there will be 1-100 in the first position and 1-15000 between "E" and "B".  I’d like to separate like the text into 6 different cells according to this key: (10)(E)(100)(B)(1)(PL1)

These equations will do that

1. @david’s first equation
2. =”E” or =MID(A1,FIND("E",A1),1)
3. @david’s second equation
4. =”B” or =MID(A1,FIND("B",A1),1)
5. =MID(A1,FIND("B",A1)+1,1)
6. =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("P",A1)+1)